# Setting Stripe API key to test env for RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, curl, rspec, stripe-payments

How do you set a Stripe API key to the test environment for RSpec?

I am trying to test whether a user could bypass the Stripe charge in the following [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) action, effectively POSTing to the resource and writing to the database (e.g. using cURL or some other tool).

```
  def create

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email        => params[:stripeEmail],
        :card         => params[:stripeToken],
    )
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer     => customer.id,
        :amount       => 1000,
    )

    if charge["paid"] == true
      @customer.create(email: params[:stripeEmail],
                       first_name: params[:first_name],
                       last_name:  params[:last_name],
                       agreed_to_terms: params[:agreed_to_terms],
                       )
      UserMailer.welcome_email(@customer).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Something went wrong! Please try again."
      redirect_to error_url
    end

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

But the spec requires me to provide an API key.

```
  describe 'POST #create' do

    context "with valid credentials" do
      it "but without Stripe, redirects to root_url" do
        @product = create(:valid_credentials)
        post :create, {first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", stripeEmail: "john@doe.com", agreed_to_terms: true}
        expect(response).to redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

as seen below

```
No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.
```

Answer (score 1):

No not unless you built that functionality.

Comment: forgot to mention that the spec says otherwise. edited @ruby_newbie

Comment: That won't redirect to the root_url because charge["paid"] will not evaluate to true.

Comment: The spec passes though @ruby_newbie

Comment: I would have to see what  StripeMock.create_test_helper/ StripeMock.start do to know but I am guessing it is creating a charge.  That said put a binding.pry in the controller to figure out what is going on is what I would do.  See if you have a charge at the point in time.

Comment: I put byebug within `if charge["paid"]` and it opened up inside that block. Does that mean it's traversing that flow? @ruby_newbie

Comment: I am not sure what byebug is but it sounds like something in the setup is also creating a charge that is paid.  If not then   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer     => customer.id,
        :amount       => 1000, is creating a charge with paid = true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71053/discussion-between-ruby-newbie-and-softcode).

Answer (score 1):

The StripeMock library is simulating a success in the before block.  Use

```
StripeMock.prepare_card_error(:missing)
```

in the before block.

Comment: After reflection, this is actually not the problem I was asking about. The nuance is that I was trying to see whether I could POST without creating a Stripe charge, as opposed to a POST with a Stripe charge that has a missing card. @ruby_newbie

Comment: You can test that but you shouldn't use stipe mocks then.  StripeMocks simulates a stripe transaction.  You should just do a plain post to the url with the info you were sending.

Comment: But then it asks for API key. Edited now @ruby_newbie

Comment: Perfect!  Now you know that no one can do a post request and create a subscription.  Personally I wouldn't ever write the test you are writing unless it was a requirement somewhere.  I think asking for an API key is a fine failure point for the attack. If someone has your API key you have bigger problems.

Comment: My concern is not with someone posting a request and creating a charge, because that is obviously something that I would want in place; rather, my concern is whether someone could post a charge to the resource without creating a charge. @ruby_newbie

Comment: But you have established that they cannot without the API key correct?

Comment: Yes but that is because in the test environment the API key is not set. In a production environment, it will be set. @ruby_newbie

Answer (score 0):

In your config/secrets.yml add the stripe tokens

```
test:
    secret_key_base: <your_secret_key>
    stripe_publishable_key: <your_stripe_publishable_key>
    stripe_secret_key: <your_stripe_secret_key>
    stripe_client_id: <your_stripe_client_id>
```

And in config/initializers/stripe.rb set your stripe_key

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.secrets.stripe_secret_key
Stripe.api_version = '2015-04-07'
```

You can get your Stripe API key in https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Remember to keep your keys safe, don't share and exclude your secrets.yml file from the version-control repository (github, bitbucket, etc)